# Broken code -- How do I properly use AJAX to prevent this section of website from loading?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

I closely followed an AJAX tutorial ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WwngGtboldU ) to learn how to prevent certain sections of a website from loading. You can see at 17:50 he clicks the links and, rather than the entire page loading, only a certain section loads in.

However, it's simply not working for me. When I click "Cats" or "Dogs", the entire page loads. It's very frustrating! Could anyone figure out what might be going wrong in my version? I've been using XAMPP, by the way, and I always test this by opening cats.php or dogs.php.

style.css

```
body{
    background-color: aqua;
}

ul#nav {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

ul#nav li {
    display:inline;
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>History API</title>
    </head>


<body>

    <nav id="main">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="cats.php">Cats</a></li>
            <li><a href="dogs.php">Dogs</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

footer.php

```
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var nav, content, fetchAndInsert;

                nav = $('nav#main');
                content = $('section#content');


                //Fetches and inserts content into the container
                fetchAndInsert = function(href) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'http://localhost/BlankApacheHistoryAPI/content' + href.split('/').pop(),
                        method: 'GET',
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(data){
                            content.html(data);
                        }                    
                    });
                }); 


                //User goes back/forward 
                $(window).on('popstate', function() {
                    fetchAndInsert(location.pathname);
                });


                nav.find('a').on('click', function(e) {
                    var href = $(this).attr('href');

                    //Manipulate history
                    history.pushState(null, null, href);

                    //Fetch and insert content
                    fetchAndInsert(href);


                    e.preventDefault();            
                });

            });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

cats.php

```
<?php
require 'views/header.php';
?>

<section id="content">
    <?php require 'content/cats.php'; ?>
</section>

<?php
require 'views/footer.php';
?>
```

content/cats.php

```
Cats say meow
```

dogs.php

```
<?php
require 'views/header.php';
?>

<section id="content">
    <?php require 'content/dogs.php'; ?>
</section>

<?php
require 'views/footer.php';
?>
```

content/dogs.php

```
Dogs say woof
```

Comment: what browser do you use?

Comment: just a quick guess, try to add `return false;` after `e.preventDefault();`. code looks ok to me though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the last forward slash:

```
url: 'http://localhost/BlankApacheHistoryAPI/content' + href.split('/').pop(),
```

should be

```
url: 'http://localhost/BlankApacheHistoryAPI/content/' + href.split('/').pop(),
```

Comment: Good catch! Doing this + removing the extra parenthesis at the end of the fetchAndInsert function fixed my problem. Works great now, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. At the end of your `fetchAndInsert = function(href)` you wrote `});` while in fact the paranthesis should be there. Change it to `};` (*hint: check your developer console (F12) to see any error messages*)
2. Remove `history.pushState(null, null, href);` - it's actually redirecting you to the link ("*the entire page loads*")